# How to take out if series of number is found before underscore in php

Tags: php, regex

Suppose, I have this string:

```
$string = "hello1711089_world86";
```

and

```
$string ="hello_something_1711089_world86_quotes";
```

the output should be->

```
$x = "hello1711089";
```

and

```
$y = "hello_something_1711089";
```

wanted single code that can be used in both cases;

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us what you've tried, and where you are stuck. See [ask] for more information. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You could also use [`preg_replace('/\d\K_.*/', "", $string);`](https://eval.in/1046676) or [`preg_split('/\d+\K_/', $string, 2)[0];`](https://eval.in/1046675)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below regex:

```
\w.*\d{7}
```

Here is the code:

```
$re = '/\w.*\d{7}/m';
$str = 'hello1711089_world86

hello_something_1711089_world86_quotes';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

[A demo for you](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/25)

Comment: yes I did. Did you use this string `hello17119_world86`? The OP didn't specify that it will have exactly 7 numbers

Comment: it doesn't say the word `ONLY` in the post. It says `_Suppose_, I have this string`. This means that the string might change.

Answer (score 0):

use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```
$string ="hello_something_1711089_world86_quotes";
$string = explode("_",$string);
echo $string[0]; //hello
```